# How to add sub application in asp core mvc project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a asp .net mvc 5 legacy project and I would like to integrate in a sub application inside my new NET framework asp core 2.1 project.

For example:

- localhost:3054(legacy project)
- localhost:5096(new mvc core project)

If I call to localhost:5096/legacy/clients I would like to get clients from localhost:3054/clients without url change localhost:5096/legacy/clients no redirects.

It's important for my to have one unique end point "/legacy" for the front end (Angular) don't call two different domains.

Comment: You could configure url rewriting rules.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Core cannot coexist in the same project and two different projects cannot be served from the same location. You can potentially put one under the other such that you'd have a URL structure like `https://sample.com` for your ASP.NET Core app and then `https://sample.com/legacy` for your ASP.NET MVC app, but they must have some difference in the location to identity which should load.

Additionally, if you do do this, then you need to be extra careful with the Web.configs for each app. In particular, you need to ensure that sections are not inherited by sub applications (as is the default), by adding `inheritInChildApplications="false"` to each section in your main app.

Comment: Thanks, so I can add sub-domain application through IIS? How can I configure this?

Comment: You just add a virtual application under your site.

Comment: So, if I use virtual application while I'm developing I will have two path(old and new) before publish or it's possible have virual application while I'm in development?

Comment: You can deploy to a local IIS, but in VIsual Studio, there's no built-in way.